# Elaboration of proof of a theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions continuous on a set $T\subset \mathbb{C}$ (where $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of all complex numbers) and converging uniformly to $f$ on $T$. Then $f$ is also continuous on
>   $T$.

The proof given in the book states:

To prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $z_0$ of $T$, we must show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $z$ belongs to $T$ and $|z_0-z|<\delta$, then $|f(z_0)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ ...

I don't understand the beginning of this proof, can anyone help elaborate?

Comment: What is $C$? Is it $\bf C$, the set of all complex numbers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes sir it is. Going to edit it.

Comment: The beginning of the proof as quoted by you here i smerely stating the definition of "$f$ is continuous at $z_0$". The proof itself starts later (and is probably a standard $\frac\epsilon3$ proof).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, it is the standard $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ proof but I dont understand the definition.

Comment: I am not sure if it will be helpful but we want to show that $f$ is continuous at every point in $T$ so if we pick an arbitrary point of $T$ and show that $f$ is continuous there since the point was arbitrary and could have been any point in $T$ it will follow that $f$ will be continuous on $T$. So we let $\varepsilon > 0$ and then we just need the $\delta>0$. You'll notice $$\left\lvert f(z_0)-f(z) \right\rvert = \left\lvert f(z_0) + f_n(z)-f_n(z)+f_n(z_0)-f_n(z_0)-f(z) \right\rvert$$ and so

Comment: so $\left\lvert f(z_0)-f(z) \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert f(z_0)-f_n(z)\right\rvert + \left\lvert f_n(z) - f_n(z_0) \right\rvert + \left\lvert f_n(z_0)-f(z) \right\rvert$ and the book I am sure has what you need etc. Continuity of $f_n$ gives the middle part, and uniform convergence will give the first and last parts of the sum, i.e. these things will let us make the quantities smaller than $\varepsilon / 3$.

Comment: @Wishingwell Thanks, but what is $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta>0$ in this problem? Like geometrically is it just a disk?

Comment: In the complex plane all the $z$ satisfying $\left\lvert z - z_0 \right\rvert < \delta$ is the set of all of points in the plane that are within $\delta$ of $z_0$ so it is a disk. Say $z = x +iy=(x,y)$ and $z_0 = x_0+iy_0=(x_0,y_0)$. Then, $$\left\lvert z - z_0 \right\rvert = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < \delta$$ if and only if $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 < \delta^2$$ and we can look at these points (x,y) in the complex plane as being in the interior of the disk with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $\delta$.

Comment: So if its continuous then for every $\varepsilon$ disk about $f(z_0)$ we can find a $\delta$ disk around $z_0$ so that the $\delta$ disk maps into the $\varepsilon$ disk.

Comment: Was going to edit my last comment and say that this is true if $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ and we look at the $\delta$ disk intersected with the domain needs to map into the $\varepsilon$ disk. Good luck ;)

Comment: @Wishingwell Thanks a lot! If you want you can leave your comments as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Thats okay. I will have to be bold next time and just submit an answer =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment-answer by Wishingwell:

We want to show that $f$ is continuous at every point in $T$ so if we pick an arbitrary point of $T$ and show that $f$ is continuous there since the point was arbitrary and could have been any point in $T$ it will follow that $f$ will be continuous on $T$. So we let $\epsilon >0$ and then we just need the $\delta >0$. You'll notice
$$|f(z_0)−f(z)|=|f(z_0)+f_n(z)−f_n(z)+f_n(z_0)−f_n(z_0)−f(z)|$$
and so 
$$|f(z_0)−f(z)|\le |f(z_0)−f_n(z)|+|f_n(z)−f_n(z_0)|+|f_n(z_0)−f(z)|$$ 
and the book I am sure has what you need etc. Continuity of $f_n$ gives the middle part, and uniform convergence will give the first and last parts of the sum, i.e., these things will let us make the quantities smaller than $\epsilon/3$.